# Two events, $A$ and $B$, satisfy $P(A)=P(B)=kP(A \cup B)$ find the possible values of $k$ and hence find $P(A|B)$ in terms of $K$

Tags: probability

> Two events, $A$ and $B$, satisfy $P(A)=P(B)=kP(A \cup B)$ find the possible values of $k$ and hence find $P(A|B)$ in terms of $K$

I have no idea on where to even start with this problem, all I know is that
$$P(A \cup B)=P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A|B)P(B)\\\Rightarrow (kP(A|B)+1)P(A\cup B)=2kP(A\cup B)\\ \Rightarrow P(A|B)=\frac{2k-1}{k}\\ \therefore k>\frac{1}{2}\\ \text{Also since} P(A|B)<1\Rightarrow \frac{2k-1}{k} \leq 1\\ \Rightarrow k \leq 1$

Answer (score 0):

(i) On the one hand, $P(A \cup B) \le P(A) + P(B) = 2P(A)$ and equality is achieved i.e., $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) = 2P(A)$ when $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events. So for the case where $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events $kP(A \cup B) = k[P(A) + P(A)] =2kP(A)$, so here $k= \frac{1}{2}$.

On the other hand, $P(A) \cup B) \ge P(A)$ and equality is achieved when $A$ and $B$ have corrolation 1 i.e., if $A$ happens then $B$ must happen and if $B$ happens then $A$ must happen. So for the case where $A$ and $B$ have corrolation 1 $kP(A \cup B) = kP(A)$ so here $k=1$.

Thus [not knowing anymore about $A$ and $B$] the scalar $k$ can be anywhere in the range $[1/2,1]$.

(ii) $P(A \cap B) = P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cup B) = [2-k^{-1}]P(A)$, as $P(A \cup B) \doteq  k^{-1}P(A)$.

Thus $P(A|B) = [2-k^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 0):

Noting what you did is already a great start.  Now, replace $P(A\cup B)$ in your expression above with the expression that it is equal to below:

$P(A)=P(B)=kP(A\cup B) = k(P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B))$

Noting again that $P(A)=P(B)$, let us just keep that in the back of our mind and get rid of some unnecessary stuff in the middle:

$P(B)=k(P(B)+P(B)-P(A\cap B))$

$P(B) = 2kP(B) - kP(A\cap B)$

Continue from there:

> $(2k-1)P(B)=kP(A\cap B)$ and so if you assume $k\neq 0$ you have $\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \dfrac{2k-1}{k}=2-\frac{1}{k}$

As for the possible values of $k$, in the case that $P(A)=P(B)=0$ then all values of $k$ are possible.  Otherwise if you assume that $P(A)\neq 0$ then you note that the expression arrived at for $P(A\mid B)$ is itself also a probability and therefore bounded in the range $[0,1]$.  A bit more algebraic manipulation with those inequalities yields the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to multiply the top equation by $k$
you would get

$$kP(A \cup B) =kP(A) + kP(B) - kP(A \cap B)$$
you know that $P(A) = P(B) = kP(A \cup B)$

So rewrite the top equation I've provided in terms of one of these, and find an expression for $P(A \cap B)$

Then use the formula for $P(A|B)$

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

I believe the answer should be
$$P(A|B) = \frac{(2k-1)}{k}$$

As probabilities are at maximum 1, you know

$$P(A|B) \leq 1$$
i.e. $$ \frac{(2k-1)}{k} \leq 1$$
$${(2k-1)} \leq k$$
$${(2k)} \leq k+1$$
$${k} \leq 1$$

In addition, you also know that 
$$P(A|B) \geq 0$$
which after following the same steps, leads to 
$$k \geq \frac12$$

And thus, the values of k are:
$$\frac 12 \leq k \leq 1$$